# Create random bool array

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to create a randomized bool array with a given length a given number of True values efficiently in Python. I could not find a single command to do so, the following does what I want (twice). Is there anything more elegant way to do it?

```
import numpy as np

def randbool(length,numtrue):
    index_array=np.random.choice(length,numtrue,replace=False)
    bool_array=np.zeros(length,dtype=bool)
    bool_array[index_array]=True
    return(bool_array)

def randbool2(length,numtrue):
    bool_array=np.hstack((np.tile(True,numtrue),np.tile(False,length-numtrue)))
    np.random.shuffle(bool_array)
    return(bool_array)

print(randbool(5,2))
print(randbool2(5,2))
```

Comment: Both of these seem fine. I suspect that the first is faster

Comment: And no, I don't think that there is a more elegant approach here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still another option:

```
def randbool(l,n):
   return np.random.permutation(l)<n
```

`np.random.permutation` randomly permute `np.arange(l)`.

Comment: Cool idea, to compare the permutations with the number of True values

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion:

```
def randbool3(length, numtrue):
    return np.random.choice(length, length, replace=False) < numtrue
```

Similar in efficiency to the first approach but a bit shorter in code

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both of your examples have small `n` and is therefore in the regime where native Python code can be faster than Numpy.  For example, given:

```
from random import shuffle

def randbool4(length, numtrue):
    arr = [False] * length
    arr[:numtrue] = [True] * numtrue
    shuffle(arr)
    return arr
```

I can execute `randbool4(5,2)` in ~4µs. Your variants take ~30µs and mozway's are similar, while obchardon's Numpy variant takes only ~6µs which is surprisingly close.

Obviously when `n` gets large then Numpy's native kernels of win, but thought it worth pointing out.